# C++ anonymous struct pointer assignment

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, anonymous-types, compiler-theory

So *no*, this is not the best way to do things. However, *for the sake of theory*, how would one successfully assign a pointer value to a pointer of an anonymous struct?

```
#pragma pack(push,1)
    struct
    {
        __int16 sHd1;
        __int16 sHd2;
    } *oTwoShort;
#pragma pack(pop)

    oTwoShort = (unsigned char*)msg; // C-Error
```

produces:

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'unsigned char *' to
>   '<unnamed-type-oTwoShort> *'

The example assumes `msg` is a valid pointer itself.

Is this possible? Since you don't have an actual type, can you even typecast?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the type with `decltype`:

```
oTwoShort = reinterpret_cast<decltype(oTwoShort)>(msg);
```

This was added in C++11 though, so it won't work with older compilers. Boost has an implementation of roughly the same ([`BOOST_PROTO_DECLTYPE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/proto/detail/decltype.hpp)) that's intended to work with older compilers. It has some limitations (e.g., if memory serves, you can only use it once per scope) but it's probably better than nothing anyway.

Comment: Does BOOST_PROTO_DECLTYPE work with types with no linkage (such as anonymous types)? I couldn't find any conclusive documentation and trying to come up with a possible implementation I always hit the issue that you can't use a type with no linkage as a template parameter in C++03 even if it's deduced from a from a function argument.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Good question. To be honest, now that you mention it I doubt I've ever tried to use it with a type that had no linkage, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 7):

I think you have to use C++11's `decltype`:

```
oTwoShort = reinterpret_cast<decltype(oTwoShort)>(msg);
```

Comment: @Di-0xide: yes, it's C++11 specific.

Answer (score 6):

```
reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*&>(oTwoShort) = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(msg);
```

But, really?

Comment: Seems to be the most portable, even more-so than using `decltype`.

Comment: @Griwes - Lol. Like I said in the OP, this is just for theory's sake. :] I'm not *actually* implementing a struct like this.

Answer (score 0):

As said you can't do a pointer cast but you can do this:

```
memcpy(&oTwoShort,&msg,sizeof(void*));
```

Comment: The spec states that pointer types do not have to be the same size, so this is technically undefined behavior.